# Search has disappeared on Drupal Commerce Kickstart site

Tags: 7, search, commerce

When I first installed Drupal Commerce Kickstart it had a search enabled in the 'User Bar First' region. Now for some reason it has disappeared and I can't find it anywhere. I have tried searching the blocks and checking the search settings. What has happened to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block that you need is actually called **'Exposed form: display_products-page'**. Since it isn't immediately obvious what this is for I must have changed the block position to 'none'. Since it doesn't have search in the block name I didn't realize it was connected to search. Simply looking at the blocks on a new Kickstart Commerce install made it obvious what I was needed. Just change the position of the 'Exposed form: display_products-page' block to 'User Bar First'.